# setState inside setTimeout react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently trying to build a rock-paper-scissor and what I intend to achieve are this logic:
after the start button clicked, a player has 3seconds to pick a weapon, if not, a random weapon will be picked for the player.

The problem:
When I picked a weapon under the 3seconds, it works just fine. But, when I intentionally let the setTimeout triggered, it is not updating the state automatically. I suspected the if conditions are not met, but I don't know why that happen.

Here is the code snippet:

```
//custom hooks//
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}

const weapons= ['rock', 'weapon', 'scissors']

const App = () => {
  const [p1Weapon, setp1Weapon] = useState("");
  const prevWeapon = usePrevious(p1Weapon);

  const getPlayerTimeout = (playerRef, setPlayer, time) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (playerRef === "") {
        setPlayer(weapons[Math.floor(Math.random() * weapons.length)]);
      }
    }, time);
  };

const startGame = () => {

    getPlayerTimeout(prevWeapon, setp1Weapon, 3000);
}

return (
...

<div>
        <button
          className="weaponBtn"
          onClick={() => {
            setp1Weapon("rock");
          }}
        >
          rock
        </button>
        <button className="weaponBtn" onClick={() => setp1Weapon("paper")}>
          paper
        </button>
        <button className="weaponBtn" onClick={() => setp1Weapon("scissors")}>
          scissor
        </button>

<button type="button" onClick={startGame}>
        Start!
      </button>
</div>
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `weapons` array does not exist... you have weapon array...`const weapon= ['rock', 'weapon', 'scissors']`

Comment: oops sorry, it just a typo in the snippet. the real code uses ```const weapons```

Answer (score 0):

if all you want to do is set a state after x time you can do this very easily like this

```
this.setState({isLoading: true},

  ()=> {window.setTimeout(()=>{this.setState({isLoading: false})}, 8000)}
);
```

this should set the value of isLoading to false after 8 seconds.

I hope it helps